# JDK 1.8.0_392 having issues with rsa.cryptoj jar

Tags: java, gradle, java-8, rsa

We recently upgrade to 1.8.0_392 from lower JDK version are we are seeing Integrity check failed with CryptoJ version, but when i lower the JDK version it was working fine without an issue, below is the error we are seeing during the deployment.

```
c.n.w.n.c.crypto.SecurityProviderLoader : Failed to load preferred JCE provider JsafeJCE at position -1 
 java.lang.SecurityException: The provider self-integrity check failed.
 at com.rsa.cryptoj.c.wZ.b(Unknown Source) ~[cryptoj-1.0.0.jar!/:5.0]
 at com.rsa.cryptoj.c.Q.a(Unknown Source) ~[cryptoj-1.0.0.jar!/:5.0]
 at com.rsa.cryptoj.c.pi.d(Unknown Source) ~[cryptoj-1.0.0.jar!/:5.0]
 at com.rsa.jsafe.provider.JsafeJCE.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[cryptoj-1.0.0.jar!/:5.0]
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_392]
```

any thoughts ?

i tried adding this Crypto Jar directly in to Lib folder but still facing the same issue
downgraded the JDK version and it was working without any issue

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about a specific programming problem. A quick search of the string "provider self-integrity check failed" yields plenty of relevant results showing similar problems all indicating that the jar must be external and not loaded via an EAR or WAR, etc. This is a classpath problem, but we have no details of loading order etc in the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You don't give a ton of details but see [this discussion](https://community.adobe.com/t5/content-server-discussions/packaging-issue-with-pdf-only-epub-works/m-p/3961189#M1663).